# Automatic Jenkins deployment

Tags: automation, jenkins, hudson

I want to be able to automate Jenkins server installation using a script.
I want, given Jenkins release version and a list of {(plugin,version)}, to run a script that will deploy me a new jenkins server and start it using Jetty or Tomcat.

It sounds like a common thing to do (in need to replicate Jenkins master enviroment or create a clean one). Do you know what's the best practice in this case?

Searching Google only gives me examples of how to deploy products with Jenkins but I want to actually deploy Jenkins.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this may require some additional setup at the beginning but perhaps could save you time in the long run. You could use a product called puppet (puppetlabs.com) to automatically trigger the script when you want.  I'm basically using that to trigger build outs of my development environments.  As I find new things that need to be modified, I simply update my puppet modules and don't need to worry about what needs to be done to recreate the environments through testing for the next go round.

Comment: Thanks! I was aiming for some simple script. As far I understand, Puppet is a heavy tool that requires several resources.